# AutoCompleteBox navigate to tapped result

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have AutoCompleteBox:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  Style="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxStyle1}">
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,20" Height="66">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

When I type something it gives me suggestions, when I click a suggestion I want to navigate to page with details, how can I make this? Is it possible to make this with InvokeCommandAction?

Comment: When you click on a suggestion is OnSelectionChanged event handler of autocomplete box called?If so you can redirect your page from that method.

Comment: Can I pass object parameter and execute command by this like in InvokeCommandAction?